# How to isolate the light diffused from a specific object?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I’m doing an interior render for a carpet company. I need to show all the carpet's colour variants in the same interior scene.

I’m rendering the carpet with a neutral colour, and then adding the various carpet colours in Photoshop. All good so far:
[image]
[image]

In real-life, the carpet would reflect its colour onto nearby objects. For example, a yellow carpet would reflect a little bit of yellow onto nearby objects:
[image]

So I want to isolate the light diffused specifically from the carpet so I can add a colour overlay in Photoshop to simulate how it would work in real-life.

I know how to get a pass with all of the scene’s diffuse light. Does anyone know how to isolate the light diffused from a specific object? I assume there's a way in the compositor to mask the diffuse light pass to only show the light diffused by the carpet...

Comment: Curious.. why not add the color to the carpet's material, and let Cycles do the indirect bounce for you?

Comment: @RobinBetts because I need to do multiple colours, and it's quicker to add them in Photoshop than render the same scene for each colour...

Comment: OK, I guess it depends on your workflow. Arranging all the carpet-textures as an image sequence, and going away for a cup of tea while they all render, seems quite attractive :)